# Unable to Sign In. Invalid username or password in tableau SAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, tableau-api, saml-2.0

I am trying to configure SAML with tableau, I am using our own IDP and tableau server as a SP, it is hosted on Amazon EC2. I am able to authenticate a user through our IDP successfully. However when it redirect to SP (Tableau server) after authentication it shows '''Unable to Sign In
Invalid username or password'''.

After doing search I find out this "Login fails: SSL offloading" at [Tableau Doc](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/saml_trouble.htm#:%7E:text=This%20error%20typically%20means%20that,in%20Tableau%20Server%20as%20jsmith%20.).

It says we have configure proxy as it does not have X-FORWARDED-PROTO header in request. I follow all the steps at [This link](https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/proxy.htm). But still no luck, I am getting same "Unable to Sign In Invalid username or password".

Can anybody help me in understanding this issue and to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues and fixe it via the following kb article:
https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/intermittent-errors-unable-to-sign-in-and-invalid-username-or-password-logging-in-using-saml

Let me know if this fixes your issue, or you've solved in any other way.

//thomas